# Why is move assignment of unordered_map slow?

Tags: c++, move, unordered-map, rvalue

I am trying to understand how the move/rvalue assignment operator works. I know that it is largely implementation-specific, but assuming that move assignment in `unordered_map` works by only swapping the underlying data pointer or size attributes, I suppose it should be extremely fast?

This is the code that I tried to run:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
 
void time_it(function<void()> f)
{
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    f();
    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto diff = end - start;
    cout << chrono::duration<double, milli>(diff).count() << " ms" << endl;
}
 
using umap = unordered_map<string, string>;
static const size_t MAP_SIZE = 1000000;
 
int main()
{
    umap m;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++)
    {
        auto s = to_string(i);
        m[s] = s;
    }
 
    time_it([&]() {
        cout << "copy\n";
        auto c = m;
    });
    time_it([&]() {
        cout << "move\n";
        auto c = move(m);
    });
}
```

It returns:

```
copy
204.4 ms
move
98.568 ms
```

How come that the move assignment operator takes so long (~100 ms)?

I compiled using `g++ test.cpp -O3`. This is what my `g++ -v` returns:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
```

Comment: What reason do we have to believe that ideaone is a good place to do benchmarking? If you're going to benchmark something, it really needs to be in a controlled and well-understood environment.

Comment: Any question that asks about performance requires that you specify the compiler, compiler version, and optimization/build settings used to build the application.

Comment: My computer gives wildly different results.  Are you asking why IDEOne produces strange timing results?

Comment: How do I check what the **optimization setting** is at for Ideone's gcc 8.3 C++14?

Comment: You measured unique_ptr differently than the rest. You include cout in the timed code.

Comment: You aren't actually measuring anything meaningful with that code.  Your `shared_ptr` copies will be optimized away.  What you're actually measuring is the time it takes to call an empty function via pointer and stop the timer.

Comment: Okay guys, I removed my `shared_ptr` vs `unique_ptr` thingie. I think I will ask that in another question if possible. For this question I will focus on the `unordered_map`.

Comment: You should remove output from time measuring. Otherwise you're mainly measuring the output and the actual work is negligible.

Comment: Still, you're not just measuring copy/move initialization, but also destruction (in the move case, that's actually _all_ you're measuring, since the compiler can see that the moved-to object is never used; it just calls `clear` on the source `unordered_map`).

Comment: @MilesBudnek actually... you are correct! I did not realize that I destructed the `c` inside `time_it`. Changed it to `c = move(m); m = c;` and it became 0 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MilesBudnek explained in his comment, I only counted the runtime for `unordered_map` destructor (i.e. the object `c`) inside my second `time_it` inner function.

I changed it to:

```cpp
    time_it([&]() mutable {
        cout << "copy\n";
        auto c = m;
        m = c;
    });
    time_it([&]() mutable {
        cout << "move\n";
        auto c = move(m);
        m = move(c);
    });
```

to make the underlying object of `c` not getting deallocated, and now it says ~`0.6 ms` using `-O0` to not let the compiler do undesirable stuff.

Thanks everyone, really sorry for my mistakes in the post!

Comment: Please remove the cout from the lambda. That is not, what you want to measure.

Comment: Also measuring `-O0` is meaning less. It doesn't let the compiler do desirable stuff, stuff that's basically required for all the zero cost abstractions in C++. I'm not sure what msvc does but both gcc and clang code generation is for a 60th area stack machine before the optimizer is let loose on it. It's the most horrible code.